# Massless limit of Dirac fermion correlation functions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, conformal-field-theory, correlation-functions, asymptotics

In the 2D massless Dirac fermion CFT we have correlation functions like
$$\langle J(z,\bar{z})J(0)\rangle \sim \frac{1}{z^2},$$
where in terms of real Euclidean coordinates $x^0,x^1$, we have $z=x^0+ix^1$, and $J = \frac{1}{2}(J_0-iJ_1)$.

I want to see how this arises a bit more concretely, from a perturbative QFT approach ("perturbative" in style, but this is a free theory so it is exact). From Ward identities the current correlation function must be schematically
$$G_{\mu\nu}(p)\equiv \int d^2x\langle J_\mu(x) J_\nu (0)\rangle e^{ixp}=G(p^2)\left(g_{\mu\nu}-\frac{p_\mu p_\nu}{p^2}\right).$$

We should be able to calculate the function $G(p^2)$ using massive Dirac propagators and take some kind of limit as $m^2\rightarrow 0$ to compare with the CFT results. We get an integral like
$$G_{\mu\nu}(p)=\int \frac{d^2 k}{(2\pi)^2} \frac{\text{Tr}\left[\gamma_\mu \left(\gamma_\rho k^\rho +m\right)\gamma_\nu \left(\gamma_\sigma (k-p)^\sigma +m\right)\right]}{(k^2+m^2)((k-p)^2+m^2)}$$
This is calculated for instance in [Adam, Bertlmann, Hofer (1993)](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02724505). The result is
$$G(p^2)=\frac{1}{\pi}\left(1-\frac{2m^2}{p^2 R}\log\left(\frac{R+1}{R-1}\right)\right),\qquad R \equiv \sqrt{1+4\frac{m^2}{p^2}}.$$
This function looks a little ugly but it is actually very common in 1-loop calculations in 2D QFT and we have $G(0)=0$ at $p^2=0$ and
$$G(p^2)\sim -\frac{2m^2}{\pi p^2} \log\frac{p^2}{m^2},\qquad p^2\gg m^2.$$

Now my question is how to compare this result for massive fermions to the CFT result. How can we take the $m^2\rightarrow 0$ limit and Fourier transform (or in opposite order) to see they agree?

Comment: Looks like you are quoting eq 14 of the cited paper, which is the 1-loop result. However, the massless Dirac correlator you had in the beginning is tree-level and can be obtained by just applying Wick's theorem.

Comment: @Meng Cheng, $J_\mu = \bar{\psi}\gamma_\mu \psi$, so it's not tree level within the Dirac theory (maybe if you bosonize it, but I want to see it from the 1-loop result).

Comment: @MengCheng, Also this correlation function is closely related to the chiral anomaly since the vector and axial current components are related simply in 2D, so this is another way to see it must not be tree level.

Comment: In any case, the question is non-existent since you are comparing results from two different theories.

Comment: I mean the Dirac theory is free, so you just get JJ correlation from Wick's theorem. What else is there to be said? Your quoted result is for Dirac coupled to U(1) gauge field.

Comment: @MengCheng, The U(1) gauge field is treated as a background field in that section of the paper and isn't involved in the calculation. The JJ correlation function is indeed calculated using Wick's theorem. There are two pairings of the fermion fields giving you two propagators forming a loop.

Comment: You are right, apologies for not reading it carefully. But eq 26 seems to be the correct result once taking $m\rightarrow 0$ limit, no?

Comment: Perhaps it is an order of limits issue. If you take $m\rightarrow 0$ first in your quoted formula for $G(p^2)$, I think it gives the right result.

Comment: @MengCheng, Eq 26 is correct and is just the Minkowski version of the formula I stated in my question but it still involves a finite mass. The asymptotic formula I have in the last line of my question is my attempt at taking $m\rightarrow 0$ in $G(p^2)$. I agree it should work out somehow, but seeing exactly how is what my question is about. If you see something I did wrong or something simple about the limit I am missing, I'd be happy if you post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $x=m^2/p^2$, then

$G=\frac{1}{\pi}\Big(1-\frac{2x}{\sqrt{1+4x}}\ln \frac{\sqrt{1+4x}+1}{\sqrt{1+4x}-1}\Big)$

Now send $x\rightarrow 0$ (so $m^2\ll p^2$), the second term becomes $2x\ln x\rightarrow 0$, and we recover the expected result.

Comment: Thanks. I was preoccupied with the log part and didn't realize G being constant was exactly the answer that was needed. I was able to do the Fourier transform and match to the CFT using one of those funny $\bar{\partial} \frac{1}{z} = \delta^{(2)}(z,\bar{z})$ identities.